# How to make a shortcut for the command kerio-kvc start, stop and restart commands?

Tags: gnome-terminal, scripts

Every time I want t use this software I have to type `/etc/init.d/kerio-kvc {start|stop|restart}` in terminal. How can I define a shortcut command in terminal to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Although the above works, you will need to write 3 aliases.

Instead I suggest you use a function (assuming sudo is needed)

```
function kerio ()
    {
    case "$1" in
        start) sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start ;;
        stop) sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc stop ;;
        restart) sudo /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc restart ;;
        *) echo 'usage kerio {start|stop|restart}' ;;
    esac
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Open the bashrc file on your /home

```
nano ~/.bashrc
```

Then create an alias for what you want, on the end of the file. Like:

```
alias startkerio='/etc/init.d/kerio-kvc start'
```

Oh, and to be possible to use your new command without relogging or rebooting do this:

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

Comment: But there's problem with promission and sudo doesn't work What should I do?

Comment: The problem is when you try to save the file? If it is, it's a case of not having write permissions, so do this:

'chmod +w ~/.bashrc'  

If it's not the case, put the result of 'ls -l ~/.bashrc' here

Comment: No, when I try `startkerio` terminal wanted permission and `sudo` doesn't work!

Comment: Well,you must see the permissions of  /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc because that's what asking for a permission.


Does kerio-kvc works with sudo when it's executed directly?

Answer (score 1):

You most likely should create a script that do that for you. Create a file somewhere in `/usr/sbin`, lets call it `script` (you can change it) then, edit it and include the following:

```
 #!/bin/bash
 /etc/init.d/kerio-kvc "$@"
```

---

#### WARNING:

For this method I'm going to use the SETUID, which is extremally dangerous if you don't know what you are doing. That said continue.

---

Now, lets set some nasty things like setting up our permissions of read and execution:

```
sudo chown root:root /usr/sbin/script
sudo chmod a-w /usr/sbin/script
sudo chmod a+x /usr/sbin/script
sudo chmod u+s /usr/sbin/script
```

Done. Now run `script {start|stop|restart}` anywhere and there it's.

Comment: I would put the script in `/usr/local/sbin` and there is no need to setuid, just call the script with sudo (Just my 2c)

Comment: @bodhi.zazen well, I'm trying to get him with the less keystrokes possible

Comment: so use a one or two letter alias rather then suggesting a security risk to save a few key strokes =) at least you added a caution.